# RazorView, use same model object for more than one template

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, model

I have a problem with trying to render two separate templates using the same object.

I have something that looks like this:

```
@Html.DisplayFor(m => Model, "TemplateOne")
@Html.DisplayFor(m => Model, "TemplateTwo")
```

The first template gets render and the second one wont.

I used .NET Reflector to step through the code to see what's going on and found this:

```
if (html.ViewDataContainer.ViewData.TemplateInfo.VisitedObjects.Contains(item))
{
     return string.Empty;
}
```

TemplateHelpers.TemplateHelper(HtmlHelper html, ModelMetadata metadata, string htmlFieldName, string templateName, DataBoundControlMode mode, object additionalViewData, ExecuteTemplateDelegate executeTemplate)

So it checks to see if the model/object has already been used to render a template and then if it has which in my example it has, it returns "" so the 2nd template won't be displayed.

I have one workaround which is to clone the model for the second template, but I'm wondering if there is something else i can do like a configuration option i can set?

Steve

Comment: There must be something else you're doing wrong, because I can't reproduce this issue. Post some more code from your View and DisplayTemplates, maybe it will help.

Comment: I also can't reproduce this (tried with MVC 3, 4 and 5).  However, one issue I have noticed is that sometimes after a build with VS2013 and MVC 5 is that one template will apparently be missing.  I actually have to modify the view that is invoking the templates, save and rebuild in order for it to work correctly.  Seems intermittent and likely to be a bug.

Comment: I'll see if I can get the same thing in a new project,  if I was to pass another property on the same model to one of those templates it works. I'll keep you posted

Comment: Ok i can repro this in a clean solution. Here is a zip with new web project and an example in: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/18857420/WebApplication1.zip browse to /Help/ i have modified the table to display two additional columns (Template one & two). (ApiGroup.cshtml) for template one it just sends the same model used to render its view to the template, and for template two it uses the controller descriptor property which works. If you fire this up you will see that template one column will be empty because the model has already been used to render ApiGroup.cshtml. Hope it makes sense

Comment: The workaround i have now is: create a wrapper model for each template, but that's insane... there must be something wrong here?

Comment: @Zabavsky  forgot to notify in previous post. I've uploaded an example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way around this for me now was to create

```
public class ModelWrapper{

      public object Model { get; set}
}
```

and pass this setting the model to whatever i actually need.

Unfortunate limitation